# Collatz Conjecture - Iteration rather than Recursion

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop, recursion, iteration

I am working on something for learning purposes where I have tackled [`Collatz`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) using recursion. If you see below I make use of `@_` and `$_` to keep the `for` alive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

sub collatz {
    my ($num, $count) = @_;
    $count++;
    if ($num == 1) {
        return $count;
    } elsif ($num % 2 == 0) {
        return collatz($num/2, $count);
    } else {
        return collatz($num*3 + 1, $count);
    }
}


my $max = 0;
my $saved = 0;

for (1..1000) {
    my $length = collatz($_, 0);
    print "Num: " . $_ . " Length: " . $length . "\n";
    if ($length > $max) {
        $max = $length;
        $saved = $_;
    }
}

print "The longest sequence starts with " . $saved . "\n";
```

I am trying to use iteration instead of recursion but I just can't think of how to tackle this. I am not after the code in the question, I just want some tips / hints on how to tackle this to get the same result.

I suspect I will need to use a `while` or an `until` field.

Any help would be appreciated, again I don't want the exact answer.

---

**Update**

Here is my second attempt, which is giving me an error of

```
Can't return outside a subroutine at answer2.pl line 38.
```

```
my $number  = 0;
my $counter = 0;

while ($number != 1000) {
  $counter++;
  if ($number == 1) {
    return $counter;
  }
  elsif ($number % 2 == 0) {
    return ($number / 2,     $counter);
  }
  else {
    return ($number * 3 + 1, $counter);
  }
  $number++;
}

print "number" . $number . "counter" . $counter . "\n";
```

Comment: Use a `while` or an `until` loop.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I was struggling to think how to do it logically also to pick up the length.

Comment: @user3076141: `while` loops are best, but the exit condition is tested only at the beginning of each iteration. It's always easier to start with an endless loop and add a `last if condition` statement to exit at the appropriate place. Then you might be able to transform the code to shift that exit point to the top, and you have turned it into a `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have [*tail recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which is nice and simple to eliminate.

Instead of `collatz` calling itself to generate the next step in the sequence, you simply change the variables in-place and loop back to the top.

In its crudest form this would be

```
sub collatz2 {
  my ($num, $count) = @_;

NEXT:
  $count++;

  if ($num == 1) {
    return $count;
  }
  elsif ($num % 2 == 0) {
    $num = $num / 2;
  }
  else {
    $num = $num * 3 + 1;
  }

  goto NEXT;
}
```

but it should be written much more nicely than that.

I ended up with this

```
sub collatz {
  my ($num) = @_;
  my $count = 1;
  while ($num > 1) {
    $num = $num % 2 ? $num * 3 + 1 : $num / 2;
    ++$count;
  }
  $count;
}
```

Comment: @Gabs00: yeah I wondered about that. But I think my final version is something that the OP is unlikely to be able to construct themselves, and it will be very obvious that it was copied if it is used literally

Comment: Putting the spoilers to one side, doesn't the above pretty much give what I already have in my recursion example? The above would still need some kind of for to finish the job right?

Comment: @user3076141: Yeah I've eliminated the recursion, which was in the `collatz` subroutine. There is no recursion any longer. A `for` loop is not recursion. I think you're over-thinking this!

Comment: Oh I see! I had a mis understanding to what recursion actually was, so yes. Using the same for and using the new sub excluding the subroutine, making it more efficient.

Comment: @user3076141: Yes, making it slightly more efficient because it doesn't use a new stack frame and a new pair of variables `$num` and `$count` at each iteration. Take a look [here to learn about recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Ok so I can see that using this method managed to shape 1 minute of the time it took to run.

What method would you use to clear this down to around 5-10 seconds?

Comment: Take a look at @Miller's answer for more optimisation. He's basically inlined the subroutine code to avoid the overhead of a call and return

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the logic that returns when the condition is met in the while.

Spoiler:

> my $iter = 0;
>  while($num != 1){ #do stuff; $iter++ }

Comment: That is helpful, so I have this. Which is giving me an error of

"Can't return outside a subroutine at answer2.pl line 38."

my $number = 0;
my $counter = 0;

while ($number != 1000) {
$counter ++;
        if ($number == 1) {
        return $counter;
        } elsif ($number % 2 == 0) {
        return ($number/2, $counter);
        } else {
        return ($number*3 + 1, $counter);
        }
$number ++;
}

print "number" . $number . "counter" . $counter . "\n";

Comment: @user3076141 try updating your question with that code.

Comment: @user3076141 hint, your while clause should not be the number of iterations you expect to be completed, and you don't use return when not using a subroutine. In any case, if this were in a subroutine, you would only need 1 return statement.

Comment: @user3076141 a better way to put it with the while statement is, expect infinite iterations until you get your desired `$number`.

Comment: @Gabs00: I had no idea there was a *hidden spoiler* mechanism in markdown. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabs00: In fact I can't find it documented anywhere. How did you find it?

Comment: @Borodin when posting, the orange square with the question mark. links to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Gabs00: Ah I remember reading that now. Clearly it didn't register as being useful at the time! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `for` or `while` loop with the end condition that your number == 1.

Spoiler:

> ```
>  use strict;
>  use warnings;
>  
>  my $max_num = 0;
>  my $max_steps = 0;
>  
>  for my $num (1..1000) {
>      my $steps = 0;
>      for (my $i = $num; $i != 1; $steps++) {
>          $i = $i % 2 ? 3 * $i + 1 : $i / 2;
>      }
>  
>      print "Num: " . $num . " Length: " . $steps . "\n";
>      if ($steps > $max_steps) {
>          $max_num = $num;
>          $max_steps = $steps;
>      }
>  }
>  
>  print "The longest sequence starts with " . $max_num . "\n";
> ```

Comment: You need `my $steps = 1` to match the OP's counting

Comment: I chose to match the more logical actual number of steps as reported in the wikipedia article about the algorithm.  Considering the OP is ultimately only worried about the number with the maximum length, I feel this is a fair decision.